# What could cause .wasm to load images so slowly?

Tags: uno-platform

In my Uno test project, it takes about **4** seconds to load 50 images into an ItemsWrapGrid on the UWP platform.  The same images take **225** seconds (3 minute 45 seconds) to load into a WrapPanel.  Since the only difference in the code is ItemsWrapGrid or WrapPanel, I'm thinking the problem is the WrapPanel, but I can't be sure, it could be in how the platforms implement the <Image ItemsSource=""/.

I don't have any experience with .wasm so I don't know if this is expected (is it?).  Is there something I can do to Optimize for wasm?

or any other thoughts?  4- minutes is just not acceptable compared to about 4 seconds.

Thanks

Thanks for asking if I could repro in Uno Playground.  I was unaware of the site.
I was NOT ABLE to repro on the playground, which led me to investigate other possibilities.
I have resolved the issue.

My design pattern was to define a single ObservableCollection without a property change notification:

```
public ObservableCollection<PictureViewModel> Pictures {get;set }
```

I would bind that to my UserControl and update by **Pictures.Clear()**.

This is my snippet that resulted in the long render time:

```
List<Picture> PictList = await DataService.GetPicturesByEvent(this.SelectedEvent.EvtKey, clubkey, skipPosition, this.PagingViewModel.PageSize);
List<PictureViewModel> PictVMList = mapper.Map<List<Picture>, List<PictureViewModel>>(PictList);
if (PictVMList != null && this.SelectedEvent != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedEvent.FilePath))
{
    this.Pictures.Clear();
    foreach (PictureViewModel item in PictVMList)
    {
        item.Parent = this;
        item.SetURL(SelectedEvent);
        this.Pictures.Add(item);
    }
    this.SelectedPicture = PictVMList.Count > 0 ? PictVMList.First() : null; 
}
```

To resolve the long render time. I:

1. Made my ObservableCollection observable.
2. Removed all instances of Picture.Clear();
3. Created a new ObservableCollection whenever it needed updating.

The Resolved code snippet is:

```
List<Picture> PictList = await DataService.GetPicturesByEvent(this.SelectedEvent.EvtKey, clubkey, skipPosition, this.PagingViewModel.PageSize);
List<PictureViewModel> PictVMList = mapper.Map<List<Picture>, List<PictureViewModel>>(PictList);
if (PictVMList != null && this.SelectedEvent != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedEvent.FilePath))
{
    foreach (PictureViewModel item in PictVMList)
    {
        item.Parent = this;
        item.SetURL(SelectedEvent);
    }
    this.SelectedPicture = PictVMList.Count > 0 ? PictVMList.First() : null;                       
}
Pictures = new ObservableCollection<PictureViewModel>(PictVMList);
```

I don't understand why my initial code pattern did not work as expected, but can live with adding an OnPropertyChanged("Pictures") notification.

Comment: I have put a stopwatch on the problem and find that in wasm it takes less than a second to actually retrieve the database records containing the image urls and to populate the ObservableCollection of Image Urls.  I also replaced the GridView with a ListView that displays the images  The ListView displays the images in about 2 seconds.  I'm guessing the added time is in the rendering.  With the GridView it takes 4-5 minutes even if I remove the image control and leave the TextBlock control.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue on https://playground.platform.uno/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the Uno Playground site.  I was unable to repro there, which caused me to look for the problem in a different direction.  I have updated my post to explain how I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of Uno 3.10, [`ItemWrapGrid` is not supported](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/468) on WebAssembly. Using the WrapPanel control will force the materialization of all the items in the list, making the performance particularly slow.

You're not specifying which control you're using as a panel, but if you're using a `ListView` control, the virtualization will be enabled, though not with the layout wrapping that you need.

If you want virtualizing grid-like layouts, you can also use the [`ItemsRepeater` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemsrepeater?view=winui-3.0), and its layouts (e.g. FlowLayout, StackLayout, or WCT's [WrapLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/layout/wraplayout)).